# Extract URL from HttpPost Android

Tags: java, android, http, http-post

I have a long URL that is being built using `nameValuePairs` and I'm currently trying to figure out why **the post is resulting in a 500 error on some devices while getting a 200 on other devices.** I need to extract the full URL from the `httppost` although as I understand it should just be in the format of:

```
http://xx.com/site.asmx?var1=blah?var2=blah
```

And the same build works on phones **while not working on tablets**. I've tried looking through my code and catching any places where a tablet may not be able to define such variables like this case:

```
final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String tmDevice;
        try{
        tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId().toString();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            tmDevice = "null";
        }
```

Here is what some of the `nameValuePairs` look like and an excerpt from the posting part of the code:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs
            .add(new BasicNameValuePair("CurrentOwnerUsername", name));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("OSVersion",
            Build.VERSION.RELEASE));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hash",
            "xxx"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("OSName", "Android"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Model", Build.MODEL));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Manufacturer",
            Build.MANUFACTURER));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IMEI", id));
    try {
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SerialNumber",
                Build.SERIAL));
    } catch (NoSuchFieldError e) {
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SerialNumber",
                "NotAvailable"));
    }
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CarrierName", carrier));
    // .add(new BasicNameValuePair("FriendlyName", Build.DEVICE));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Type", " "));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("VisitorID", VisitorID));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PhoneNumber", phoneNumber));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SSID", ssid));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MACAddress", macAddr));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserDepartment",
            department_val));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("BatteryLevel", batteryText));

    int toastDuration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL); // post object
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); // execution
        int result = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (result == 200) {
            CharSequence toastText = "Success";
            Toast.makeText(context, toastText, toastDuration).show();
        } else {
            CharSequence toastText = "Failure";
            Log.d("checkin", String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine()
                    .getStatusCode()));
            Toast.makeText(context, toastText, toastDuration).show();
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        CharSequence toastText = "ClientProtocolException";
        Toast.makeText(context, toastText, toastDuration).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        CharSequence toastText = "IOException";
        Toast.makeText(context, toastText, toastDuration).show();
    }
```

So what I need is a way to pull the completed URL from the `httppost`. the current string `URL` being passed is simply a base url such as : http://xx.com/ and the `nameValuePairs` follow it.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `HttpPost`, the values are passed as the body of the request, so the URL is going to be the same as the one you pass in. You can, however, use [`EntityUtils.toString(HttpEntity entity)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html) with your UrlEncodedFormEntity to print out the values that will be passed in the `HttpPost`.

Comment: it shows just the paramters, but not the COMPLETE URL WITH PARAMS

Comment: I don't know why but I get "" ?